# Is there any alternatives to boost::intrusive_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers, boost-smart-ptr

I have some code which uses boost::intrusive_ptr. The advantages of using boost::intrusive_ptr over std::shared_ptr is interesting to me. I read about these from these [two](http://baptiste-wicht.com/posts/2011/11/boost-intrusive_ptr.html) [blogs](https://kinestheticcoding.wordpress.com/tag/intrusive_ptr/).

I would like to know if I could replace boost::intrusive_ptr with something else. I can replace boost::scoped_ptr with std::unique_ptr by enabling c++11 support. The motive for this change is that I need to bundle whole boost library (only headers) with the source. Note that, I am not using linking to boost libraries anywhere in my code.

I would be glad, if someone knows an alternative to boost::intrusive_ptr or boost's smart pointers in general.

Comment: You can just write your own. Or, `std::make_shared` is to some degree an alternative in that it avoids the creation of a separate control block object. But that doesn't help for e.g. COM classes.

Comment: I dont have COM classes. So I think writing own is only option. BTW, std::make_shared have any performance issue as I read in the blog (link in the question)

Comment: Is there any alternative libraries for boost::smart_ptr. I head of loki library. But it seems highly inactive.

Comment: You can easily take the intrusive_ptr header from boost source code, then remove all boost dependencies from it. In an hour or two, you'll get a completely standalone intrusive_ptr implementation.